# How to change the content moderation state in a custom submit handler?

Tags: 8, forms, workflows

I am trying to change the content moderation state from `draft` to `submitted` programatically.  The Content Moderation module adds a field to content types with a dropdown to change the state, but I want to hide this field from users and instead show a custom submit handler that changes the form state.

I can change the default value of the moderation field with code like this:

```
  $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = "submitted";
```

But, how do I change the value for the content moderation field using `$form_state` in the submit handler?

```
  $form_state->setValue('moderation_state', 'submitted');`
```

does not work like it does for fields.

Here is the debug output for `kint($form['moderation_state']['widget'][0])`:

[image: kint debug output]

Comment: Debug $form_state, not $form. If the form uses #tree, then the values in form_state are in arrays: `$form_state->setValue(['foo', 'bar'], $value);` see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AsetValue/8.4.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the moderation state you need first to get the entity:

```
$entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
```

and then change the state:

```
$entity->set('moderation_state', 'submitted');
```

and save:

```
$entity->save();
```

All the code:

```
/**
 * Submit callback to submit for approval
 */
function draft2submit_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  // Getting the entity.
  $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  // Changing the moderation state.
  $entity->set('moderation_state', 'submitted');
  // Saving the entity.
  $entity->save();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve this problem too, and found two ways to do it:

**Option 1:**

Set the widget type to value, and set the default value to `submitted`. I also removed the current state message showing on the form

```php
    /**
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */
    function your_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    
      // may want to do some checks here ...
    
      $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['current']['#access'] = false;
      $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#type'] = 'value';
      $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'submitted';
    }
```

Using Option 1 this could fail validation if the current moderation state doesn't have a transition to `submitted` for the current user.

**Option 2:**

Add a validation callback function, and set the value in there:

```php
    /**
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */
    function your_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    
      // may want to do some checks here ...
    
      $form['moderation_state']['#access'] = false;
    
      if (isset($form['#validate'])) {
        array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_your_module_set_moderation_state_to_submitted');
      } else {
        $form['#validate'][] = '_your_module_set_moderation_state_to_submitted';
      }
    }
    
    /**
     * @param $form
     *   Nested array of form elements that comprise the form.
     * @param $form_state
     *   The current state of the form.
     */
    function _your_module_set_moderation_state_to_submitted(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $form_state->setValue(['moderation_state', '0', 'value'], 'submitted');
    }
```

I found I needed to use a validation callback, as otherwise it would run the validation before attempting to set the value, this would fail the validation if I didn't have a transition configured for it to remain at the same moderation state.

The other thing to note with Option 2 is that by using `setValue` you add a validated value. Therefore depending on how you've configured your workflows that may not be a transition that is otherwise allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to change the moderation state.

```php
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$moderation_state = $node->moderation_state->value;
$is_approver = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())->hasRole('approver');

switch ($moderation_state) {
  case 'draft':
    if ($is_approver) {
      if (!empty($node->get('publish_on')->value)) {
        $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'scheduled_publish';
      }
      else {
        $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'draft';
      }
    }
    else {
      $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'draft';
    }
    break;
  case 'needs_review':
    if ($is_approver) {
      if (!empty($node->get('publish_on')->value)) {
        $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'scheduled_publish';
      }
      else {
        $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'draft';
      }
    }
    else {
      $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'draft';
    }
    break;
  case 'scheduled_publish':
    $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'scheduled_publish';
    break;
  default:
    $form['moderation_state']['widget'][0]['state']['#default_value'] = 'draft';
    break;
}
```